# How To Set Angular md-toolbar background color

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to set the background color in angular using md-toolbar directive i don't want to use the css in the style tag i want to do this by in md-toolbar directive this is my angular code

```
<md-toolbar class="md-hue-2">
<div class="md-toolbar-tools">
<p><strong>Classified Store</strong></p>
  <md-button>
<md-icon class="mdi mdi-plus-circle"></md-icon>
Classified Press Button
 </md-button>
</div>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: why cant you use a class?

Comment: "I want to do this one way I don't want to do it another" type questions generally are examples of [XY Problems](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).  You are asking about the solution, but aren't describing why the generally accepted practice won't work for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the an angular material theme that you have defined in your code, you can use the [md-theme](https://material.angularjs.org/1.1.1/Theming/04_multiple_themes) attribute, or you can define a css class that sets the background color. Other wise you'll need use the `style` or `ng-style` tag to set the background color. You can bind a `$scope` variable to the `ng-style` attribute with the main color of your app, and re-use it wherever you need.